# Return to previous major version

Tags: versioning

I wonder if it is posible to have a file to return to a previous published major version. The scenarios is this; 
I have a file that is in version 2.5, currently the latest published version is 2.0. By "mistake" I press publish and the document becomes 3.0. I then decide to unpublish the 3.0. The document then correctly returns to 2.5. However, I now have no major version published. This is a problem as we're planning on using Content Deployment that only pick major versions. Can this behaviour be changed somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can roll back to any version of the document by going into the Version History settings for the item and finding the version you want and telling it to Restore that version.